# Determine all stores for a CMS page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, store

I do have the problem, that I want to list the CMS pages on a site for a store. When I get my collection like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($storeId)->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1);
```

I get all the pages, which have "All StoreViews" as set stores as well. Thats kind of obvious, because they are also for that specific store. The problem is, that I just want to get the pages which are for that specific store **only**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh I found the solution randomly. The method addStoreFilter() has a second argument. If you set it to false, it just returns the pages I want to get. Maybe a hint for someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$cmsPage = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1);
```

May be help you !